Updating to 10.2.6 fails "autoconfigure" on core
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548043/drupal-updating-to-10-2-6-fails-autoconfigure-on-core
Link to stackoverflow i opened.
I still have the issue, while trying to upgrade to 10.2 or 10.3 . I successfully reverted the site to 10.1.8 but i can't find the cause of the error.

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The configuration key "autoconfigure" cannot be used to define a default value in "core/core.services.yml". Allowed keys are "public", "tags", "autowire". in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->parseDefaults() (line 161 of /var/www/suneris/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/YamlFileLoader.php). Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->parseDefaults(Array, 'core/core.services.yml') (Line: 129) Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->parseDefinitions(Array, 'core/core.services.yml') (Line: 102) Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->load('core/core.services.yml') (Line: 1301) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 934) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 42) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 494) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 65) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 27)

As i undestand the docs the autoconfigure:true is the default value of the clean file so i don't understand why the system doesn't recognize it.
Composer.json:
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^2.0",
    "drupal/bootstrap5": "^3.0",
    "drupal/captcha": "^2.0",
    "drupal/cookies": "^1.2",
    "drupal/core": "^10.1.8",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "10.1.8",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "10.1.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "10.1.8",
    "drupal/dxpr_theme": "^5.2",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.11",
    "drupal/google_tag": "^2.0",
    "drupal/metatag": "^2.0",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.17",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.12",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.2",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^4.1",
    "drupal/token": "^1.14",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.3",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "^4.3",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.2",
    "drush/drush": "^12.4"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "web/"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}

result of Composer show symfony/*:
composer show 'symfony/*'
symfony/console                    6.4.9  Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces

symfony/dependency-injection       6.4.9  Allows you to standardize and centralize the way objects are constructed in your application

symfony/deprecation-contracts      3.4.0  A generic function and convention to trigger deprecation notices

symfony/error-handler              6.4.9  Provides tools to manage errors and ease debugging PHP code

symfony/event-dispatcher           6.4.8  Provides tools that allow your application components to communicate with each other by dispatching events and listening to them

symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts 3.4.2  Generic abstractions related to dispatching event

symfony/filesystem                 6.4.9  Provides basic utilities for the filesystem

symfony/finder                     6.4.8  Finds files and directories via an intuitive fluent interface

symfony/http-foundation            6.4.8  Defines an object-oriented layer for the HTTP specification

symfony/http-kernel                6.4.9  Provides a structured process for converting a Request into a Response

symfony/mailer                     6.4.9  Helps sending emails

symfony/mime                       6.4.9  Allows manipulating MIME messages

symfony/polyfill-ctype             1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for ctype functions

symfony/polyfill-iconv             1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for the Iconv extension

symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme     1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's grapheme_* functions

symfony/polyfill-intl-idn          1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's idn_to_ascii and idn_to_utf8 functions

symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer   1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's Normalizer class and related functions

symfony/polyfill-mbstring          1.28.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension

symfony/polyfill-php72             1.30.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions

symfony/polyfill-php80             1.30.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions

symfony/polyfill-php81             1.30.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.1+ features to lower PHP versions

symfony/polyfill-php83             1.28.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.3+ features to lower PHP versions

symfony/process                    6.4.8  Executes commands in sub-processes

symfony/psr-http-message-bridge    6.4.8  PSR HTTP message bridge

symfony/routing                    6.4.8  Maps an HTTP request to a set of configuration variables

symfony/serializer                 6.4.9  Handles serializing and deserializing data structures, including object graphs, into array structures or other formats like X...

symfony/service-contracts          3.4.2  Generic abstractions related to writing services

symfony/string                     6.4.9  Provides an object-oriented API to strings and deals with bytes, UTF-8 code points and grapheme clusters in a unified way

symfony/translation-contracts      3.4.2  Generic abstractions related to translation

symfony/validator                  6.4.9  Provides tools to validate values

symfony/var-dumper                 6.4.9  Provides mechanisms for walking through any arbitrary PHP variable

symfony/var-exporter               6.4.9  Allows exporting any serializable PHP data structure to plain PHP code

symfony/yaml                       6.4.8  Loads and dumps YAML files

Any leads?

Did you rebuild cache after the update?

Yes i rebuilt it with drush cache:rebuild i assume you don't need more steps?

Under normal circumstances that’s all you’d do, yeah. It seems like a caching issue, as there’s not much chance that a stable release of Drupal contains  routing parameters that aren’t compatible with the same version of core. Restarting VMs/servers would be the next thing I’d try

i don't have permissions right now to restart apache nor nginx so i guess i need to talk to our host providers? I feel its so much work for an update... Also i updated to 10.2.2 as its the first release on security maintenance. I guess i should do it all again for 10.3.0 and more?

Ideally you'd spin up a local copy of the site first, to determine if the problem is definitely environment-specific, then go from there (yes contact the host if it's only broken in their environment and you can't administer the servers). Assuming the contrib/custom module you have installed support it, it would make more sense to go straight to 10.3.1 and ignore other versions. Drupal uses semver, so in theory 10.1 -> 10.3 contains no breaking changes. It doesn't always go that way though, so again, a local copy of the site is the best way to start

It looks like the symfony libraries are incongruent with Drupal’s container configuration. composer show “symfony/*” would be interesting.

I edited to show the return of composer show 'symfony/*'

How did you update the composer project? Normally a composer update should update all Symfony components, so that core.service.yml can use autoconfigure. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3357408

i followed the usual routine i have, updating drush, and then updating with composer :
composer require drupal/core-recommended drupal/core-composer-scaffold drupal/core-project-message --update-with-all-dependencies
then doing a drush updb and drush cr.
But i really think it's a config issue between my drupal and symfony core ?  since reverting to 10.1.8 works ....
Maybe a file or module

The symfony dependencies look pretty much as expected by using drupal/core-recommended at 10.2.7.

I tried the drupal/core-recommended, still the same error, I'm starting to think ill have to do a fresh install on the test env to see where it breaks....
Any way to clear Drupal efficiently ? Since i don't even know if it comes from the Database or not it may even break again when i import it.

Im contacting my host to see if upgrading from php 8.1 to php8.3 could solve the matter. If it's not i have no more leads to why it breaks
